# Variadic templates double-ended pack workaround

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

The following code compiles because I'm assuming that `parent` of `Object<Parent, T, Rest...>` itself has no parent.

```
template <typename Parent, typename T, typename... Rest>
struct Object {
    T item;  // T is item's type, while Parent is parent's item's type.
    Object<T, Rest...>* child;  // child's item type is the first type from Rest...
    Object<void, Parent, T, Rest...>* parent;
    Object(const T& t) : item(t) {}
    void setChild (Object<T, Rest...>* c) {
        child = c;
        child->setParent(this);
    }
    void setParent (Object<void, Parent, T, Rest...>* p) {parent = p;}
};

template <typename Parent, typename T>
struct Object<Parent, T> {  // Has no child.
    T item;
    Object<void, Parent, T>* parent;
    Object(const T& t) : item(t) {}
    void setParent (Object<void, Parent, T>* p) {parent = p;}
};

template <typename... Args>
using ObjectWithNoParent = Object<void, Args...>;

int main() {
    ObjectWithNoParent<int, char, double> object(2);
    Object<int, char, double> child('r');
    object.setChild(&child);
    Object<char, double> grandChild(3.5);
//    child.setChild(&grandChild);  // Want this line to work.
}
```

What workaround can I use so that I can replace the type `void` with a general type?

Comment: to be clear: How do you want the initialization to look like?

Comment: As `Parent` will have to know its own `Parent`, the final `Child` will have the whole hierarchy as Parent type...

Comment: @bolob.  The commented out line in main shows what I would like to have.  @Jarod42, so if I decare `grandchild` as `Object<int, char, double> grandChild;` instead, then the whole thing will ultimately be possible?  But that would mean that the pack needs `...` at both ends, loosely speaking, won't it (hence the title)?

Comment: I got this, I hope I remember to make it into a full answer later: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/590616d7a4bb1647

Comment: @At Mooing Duck. Yes, using an integer to identify the value-type was what I was thinking of too as I drove home. You might want to check out cdhowie's solution too, which doesn't force us to count with our eyes which one is the value type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler has to be able to tell where one argument pack begins and another ends.  To this end, what you ask is not *directly* possible, but there is a workaround: use another variadic template as a "pack delimiter."

Our goal will be to support a type like this:

```
Object<pack<A, B>, C, pack<D, E>> foo;
```

In this case, `C` is `foo`'s value type and it will have the following related types:

```
Object<pack<A>, B, pack<C, D, E>> foo_parent;
Object<pack<A, B, C>, D, pack<E>> foo_child;
```

Parent-less types will have an empty first pack and child-less types will have an empty second pack.

This is complicated a lot by the fact that you can't "recurse backwards" through variadic arguments, so the types that have parents will be a bit obfuscated.  (Unfortunately the approach `template <typename... Types, typename Last> struct foo` doesn't work because a parameter pack has to be the *last* thing in a template argument list.)  We'll need more helpers to obtain and also "peel off" the last type in a variadic pack (change `pack<A, B, C>` into `pack<A, B>`).

We will start with our declaration of `pack`:

```
// Helper template; needs no definition since we never instantiate it.
template <typename...> struct pack;
```

Now we need a helper to obtain the last type in a pack; given `pack<A, B, C>` it should let us obtain `C`.  To do this we define a meta-function that will remove types from the beginning of the pack until there is only one left.

```
// Helper to allow us to obtain the last type from a pack.
template <typename> struct last_type_in_pack;

template <typename T>
struct last_type_in_pack<pack<T>>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename First, typename... Types>
struct last_type_in_pack<pack<First, Types...>>
    : public last_type_in_pack<pack<Types...>> { };
```

Now we need the helper to turn `pack<A, B, C>` into `pack<A, B>`. We'll use this when building the parent type for an object.  This meta-function works by starting with the template arguments `pack<>, pack<A, B, C>` and moving the left-most type of the right pack to the right-most position in the left pack. When the right-most pack has one remaining type, the left-most pack is our final type.

If this is hard to follow, here are the steps:

1. Start with `pack<>, pack<A, B, C>`. The right pack has more than one element, so we continue.
2. Now we have `pack<A>, pack<B, C>`. The right pack still has more than one element.
3. Now we have `pack<A, B>, pack<C>`. The right pack has one element, so the left pack is our final type.

The implementation:

```
// We need another helper to allow us to "peel off" the last type from a pack,
// turning pack<A, B, C> into pack<A, B> for example.
template <typename, typename> struct remove_last_type_from_pack_impl;

template <typename... Types, typename LastType>
struct remove_last_type_from_pack_impl<pack<Types...>, pack<LastType>>
{
    typedef pack<Types...> type;
};

template <typename... TS1, typename T2, typename... TS2>
struct remove_last_type_from_pack_impl<pack<TS1...>, pack<T2, TS2...>>
    : public remove_last_type_from_pack_impl<pack<TS1..., T2>, pack<TS2...>> { };

template <typename>
struct remove_last_type_from_pack;

template <typename... Types>
struct remove_last_type_from_pack<pack<Types...>>
    : public remove_last_type_from_pack_impl<pack<>, pack<Types...>> { };
```

Now our actual declaration of `Object`.  We do not define it, because we will be providing partial specializations for every intended instantiation.  If someone tries to use this template with arguments we don't support they'll just get an "incomplete type" error, which is what we want.

```
template <typename...> struct Object;
```

Partial specialization allowing "double-ended" packs, and requiring at least one parent type and one child type.  (`FirstParent` exists solely to enforce that this partial specialization won't match when the first pack is empty.)

```
template <typename FirstParent, typename... ParentTypes,
          typename T,
          typename FirstChild, typename... ChildTypes>
struct Object<pack<FirstParent, ParentTypes...>, T, pack<FirstChild, ChildTypes...>>
{
    // We'll shift the packs around T to define our child and parent types:
    typedef Object<pack<FirstParent, ParentTypes..., T>,
                   FirstChild,
                   pack<ChildTypes...>> child_type;

    typedef Object<
        typename remove_last_type_from_pack<pack<FirstParent, ParentTypes...>>::type,
        typename last_type_in_pack<pack<FirstParent, ParentTypes...>>::type,
        pack<T, FirstChild, ChildTypes...>> parent_type;

    T item;
    child_type * child;
    parent_type * parent;

    Object(T const & t) : item(t) { }
    Object(T && t) : item(std::move(t)) { }
};
```

Now we need specializations for parent-less and child-less.

The parent-less type is relatively simple:

```
template <typename T, typename FirstChild, typename... ChildTypes>
struct Object<pack<>, T, pack<FirstChild, ChildTypes...>>
{
    typedef Object<pack<T>, FirstChild, pack<ChildTypes...>> child_type;

    T item;
    child_type * child;

    Object(T const & t) : item(t) { }
    Object(T && t) : item(std::move(t)) { }
};
```

Now the child-less type.  As before, `FirstParent` just ensures that we have at least one parent type.

We have to do the same gymnastics to obtain the parent type.

```
template <typename FirstParent, typename... ParentTypes, typename T>
struct Object<pack<FirstParent, ParentTypes...>, T, pack<>>
{
    typedef Object<
        typename remove_last_type_from_pack<pack<FirstParent, ParentTypes...>>::type,
        typename last_type_in_pack<pack<FirstParent, ParentTypes...>>::type,
        pack<T>> parent_type;

    T item;
    parent_type * parent;

    Object(T const & t) : item(t) { }
    Object(T && t) : item(std::move(t)) { }
};
```

Note that at this point `Object<pack<>, T, pack<>>` can't be instantiated since no specialization matches it, and the base template isn't defined. This type doesn't really make much sense, IMO, but you can specialize `Object` for it if you want:

```
template <typename T>
struct Object<pack<>, T, pack<>>
{
    T item;

    Object(T const & t) : item(t) { }
    Object(T && t) : item(std::move(t)) { }
};
```

If you still want your `ObjectWithNoParent` template alias, here is what that would look like now:

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Rest>
using ObjectWithNoParent = Object<pack<>, Arg, pack<Rest...>>;
```

([Here is a sample](http://ideone.com/ZRfLP1) that doesn't do much, but it does show that this compiles and it asserts that parent and child types are what we expect.)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent solution and text-book explanation.  I tested that the second `pack<...>` used is not needed since we do know where that second `pack` begins (always the second type after the first `pack`).  Thanks very much!

Comment: @prestokeys Yup, that is true. For some reason that didn't come to mind. Thankfully that's an easy change.